# Checking for proxy connection

Tags: http, sockets, proxy, socks

What do i need to send to a proxy server (http or socks) that will tell me if it is connected to the host i specified it to connect to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither proxy protocol provides that functionality.  There is no way to query a proxy to see what server it is connected to, or whether it is a still connected to a server.  If you tell it to connect to a server, then you have to assume it is always connected to that server as long as you have a valid connection with the proxy.  If the proxy loses its connection to the server, then it needs to close the connection with your client.